# How to grammatically explain the mistake in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

I think the grammatically correct version of

> Some people will post anything that is not even important for getting attention from others.

is

> People would post anything that's not even important just to get attention.

But I'm not quite sure how would you explain the first sentence mistake grammatically.

Comment: Please explain why you prefer the second. It might depend on context which version is better, but in most contexts I can think of the first is fine: you are describing what people do, not what they might do.

Comment: i see, the context is about how social media changed our society, tbh im not sure if it is grammatically , or it simply sounded really odd.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a question of your examples being correct or incorrect grammatically, but they aren't using the correct structure for what you are trying to say.  **that's not even** is a cumbersome way of using the connector **whether or not**.

I would put it in writing as *people would post anything **whether it's important or not** just to get attention*.

I think the way you phrase it in your question sounds like you are trying to convey in writing spoken mannerisms.

Comment: yeah i think you're right, that sounds alot better. totally forgot " whether or not "